# How to get rid off the empty values (0 values) using table() function in R

Tags: r

I have a simple question. I want to do a frequency table with 3 variables of my original table. If I do

```
as.data.frame(table(df$var1,df$var2,df$var3))
```

as it provides every possible combination of the 3 variables -and I have many values for each variable-, I get the error: "attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements".

The problem is that many of the combinations are actually empty. In other words, there is a 0 frequency for a lot of those possible combinations, and so I was wondering how to make R to keep into account only the non-null frequencies (so that the function table() works with my 3 variables without giving the error message.

Any idea?

Thank you very much for reading.

A very simplified table (not my original one -as I have many values so that the Cartesian product of the three when running "as.data.frame(table())¨ goes beyond de 2^31 elements- could be:

```
var1           var2           var3   var4  var5
0               a1            1234     a     1
1               a2            1234     b     2
1               a2            1235     c     2
1               a2            1235     a     7
1               a1            1235     d     3
```

And what I want is the frequencies of the first 3 variables together through the code:

```
as.data.frame(table(df$var1,df$var2,df$var3))
```

This is something I was trying:

```
subset(table(df$var1,df$var2,df$var3),table(df$var1,df$var2,df$var3)$Freq!='0')
```

Or

```
droplevels(table(df$var1,df$var2,df$var3))
```

with no luck.

In the case outlined for my example, the code as.data.frame(table(df$var1,df$var2,df$var3)) provides a table like this -as you know, creating an extra variable "Freq" that gives the time each combination of the 3 variables in the line occurs-:

```
var1           var2           var3   Freq
0               a1            1234     1 
0               a1            1235     0
0               a2            1234     0 
0               a2            1235     0
1               a1            1234     0 
1               a1            1235     1
1               a2            1234     1 
1               a2            1235     1
```

But, as I say, as there are many lines with frequency 0, making R not to take them into account when running the function table(), may simplify remarkably the calculations with way less elements than 2^31, so that an outcome may be provided without any error message. So, if available, after applying this workaround, the outcome I would expect is something like this (where all the lines with Freq=0 are not calculated when running table()):

```
var1           var2           var3    Freq
0               a1            1234     1 
1               a1            1235     1
1               a2            1234     1 
1               a2            1235     1
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducible example, but perhaps try: `library(dplyr); inowner %>% count(relhh, identificatiehuis, IDNR)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, @JasonAizkalns. I think I made it a bit more clear after editing. I thought of not giving a reproducible example as the only way to get the error is by way of a real example with many rows (that cannot fit in this frame for discussion), and I thought what the code -as.data.frame(table())- does was generally speaking, well known. Thank you again.

Comment: Actually, only applying table() to two of the variables gives an outcome with 424 million combinations. Imagine adding the extra third variable

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found the solution. It´s basically:

a <- summarise(group_by(df,var1,var2,var3),count =n())